# How to assign default values to tuple struct members

Tags: rust

How to automatically assign default values to tuple struct members

```
struct A(f64, i32);

fn main() {
    let mut a: A; // expect a.0 = 0.0, a.1 = 0
    // even below 2 line code doesn't compile
    // a.0 = 1.2;
    // a.1 = 3;

    println!("{}, {}", a.0, a.1);
}
```

But I'm getting below error

```
error[E0381]: used binding `a` isn't initialized
 --> src/main.rs:5:24
  |
4 |     let mut a: A; // expect a.0 = 0.0, a.1 = 0
  |         ----- binding declared here but left uninitialized
5 |     println!("{}, {}", a.0, a.1);
  |                        ^^^ `a.0` used here but it isn't initialized
  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `#[derive(Default)]` and initialize with [`A::default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/default/trait.Default.html#tymethod.default) (or `Default::default()`):

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct A(f64, i32);

fn main() {
    let mut a = A::default(); // expect a.0 = 0.0, a.1 = 0
    
    println!("{}, {}", a.0, a.1);
}
```